# In Javascript, why is ShiftLeft no longer supported? How can I detect which shift key is being pressed?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ubuntu, keyboard-events, shift

Upon pressing the left and the right shift keys on the keyboard, this code

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', (e)=>{console.log(e.code);});
```

used to output

```
ShiftLeft
ShiftRight
```

But now

```
ShiftLeft
ShiftLeft <---------- Why?
```

`e.location` is also always `1` and `e.keycode` is always `16` (although this is going to be deprecated.)

How can I know which shift is being pressed? And does anyone know why this support was removed? I can't seem to find any documentations or release notes on this.

Comment: It still works for me on firefox 90, I can't reproduce the issue

Comment: Works fine for me on Chrome 92 as well. Maybe some kind of binding you have on your machine/keyboard?

Comment: It works for me too on chrome

Comment: Works as expected in FF 91, Chrome 92 and Edge 92

Comment: Which browse/version are you experiencing the issue with?

Comment: Yeah it seems to work on Firefox for me as well. I am using Chrome Version 92.0.4515.131 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Ubuntu 16.04. Yeah I wonder if there is anything specific to my computer or on Ubuntu+Chrome issue.